# Word press and PHP error caused these errors

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, warnings

> Warning: Declaration of Thesis_Comment::start_lvl(&$output, $depth,
>   $args) should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth =
>   0, $args = Array) in
>   /data/25/0/30/26/30678/user/31318/htdocs/dkbinc.net/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/lib/functions/comments.php
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: Declaration of Thesis_Comment::end_lvl(&$output, $depth,
>   $args) should be compatible with Walker::end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0,
>   $args = Array) in
>   /data/25/0/30/26/30678/user/31318/htdocs/dkbinc.net/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/lib/functions/comments.php
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: Declaration of Thesis_Comment::start_el(&$output, $comment,
>   $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker::start_el(&$output,
>   $object, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $current_object_id = 0) in
>   /data/25/0/30/26/30678/user/31318/htdocs/dkbinc.net/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/lib/functions/comments.php
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: Declaration of Thesis_Comment::end_el(&$output, $comment,
>   $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker::end_el(&$output,
>   $object, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in
>   /data/25/0/30/26/30678/user/31318/htdocs/dkbinc.net/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/lib/functions/comments.php
>   on line 0

any help on resolving this error would be great!, thanks

Comment: Your theme needs to be updated to be compatible with more recent versions of PHP I suggest contacting your theme author.

Comment: That does not seem like an option, I can't find any contact information for the provider.

Comment: I have now crashed the website including the dash board by simply changing (&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = Array)  in on sections and can even load back up